# MySQLi Update data in a table

Tags: mysqli

Please help me out with this. Basically to update an existing table (chem_users) with data using 2 keys UserId & Password (or only 1 primary key is allowed?). 
Using MySQLi, what is wrong with this syntax.

```
$sql = "UPDATE chem_users SET (Prj1, Prj2) VALUES ('{$_POST['kinetics']}',  
'{$_POST['thermo']}') WHERE (UserId=JohnKing Password=1234rewq)";
```

I got this error:
Error saving user data You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(Prj1, Prj2) VALUES ('kinetics' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Try using this syntax:

```
$sql="UPDATE `chem_users` SET `Prj1`=".$_POST['kinetics'].",`Prj2`=".$_POST['thermo']." WHERE `UserId`='JohnKing' AND `Password`='1234rewq'";
```

By the way, you shouldn't just concatenate a variable inside a query like you are doing,you should use Prepared Statements.You can learn a little bit about it in this link: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Txs for the tip. I am checking on the Prepared Statement. Problem with w3s is it does not give wide range examples. Is there any other better site for MySQLi, PHP SQL? Many txs

Comment: You could try looking at the offcial website. Just search for Prepared Statements php.net on google.

Comment: I have tried this but it isn't working. Below my syntax:    $sql="UPDATE `chem_users` SET `Prj1`=".$_POST['kinetics'].",`Prj2`=".$_POST['thermo']." WHERE `UserId`='JohnKing' AND `Password`='1234rewq'";

Comment: Is any kind of error being displayed on the screen?

Comment: Same as before. Now regarding using Prepared Statement, I do not know how to run the syntax as w3s does not have an example similar to my case.